SAS Proc transpose wide to long multiple variables
I had some data with a long text string that contained data with certain dates within them. I parsed out each individual text section and the corresponding date into different columns. Each ID will have repeats of each character variable. I would like to transpose these variables from wide to long and match them to their correct ID, while also using one character variable and date per observation. I know that description doesn't do it justice so I will post some sample data below.
data test;
length status_01 $175 status_02 $175 status_03 $175;
infile datalines dsd dlm="|" truncover;
input ID Status_01$ date_01 :mmddyy10. Status_02$ date_02 :mmddyy10. Status_03$ date_03 :mmddyy10.;
format date_01 date_02 date_03 mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1 |example status on 01/29/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 01-29-23 |example status on 02/06/24 with even more text| 02-06-24 |example status on 03/11/24 with yet again more text| 03-11-24
1 |example status on 01/29/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 01-29-23 |example status on 02/06/24 with even more text| 02-06-24 |example status on 03/11/24 with yet again more text| 03-11-24
1 |example status on 01/29/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 01-29-23 |example status on 02/06/24 with even more text| 02-06-24 |example status on 03/11/24 with yet again more text| 03-11-24
2 |example status on 07/17/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 07-17-23 |example status on 12/16/23 with even more text| 12-16-23 |example status on 12/24/23 with yet again more text| 12-24-23
2 |example status on 07/17/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 07-17-23 |example status on 12/16/23 with even more text| 12-16-23 |example status on 12/24/23 with yet again more text| 12-24-23
2 |example status on 07/17/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 07-17-23 |example status on 12/16/23 with even more text| 12-16-23 |example status on 12/24/23 with yet again more text| 12-24-23
3 |example status on 04/26/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 04-26-23 |example status on 05/29/23 with even more text| 05-29-23 |example status on 07/10/23 with yet again more text| 07-10-23
3 |example status on 04/26/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 04-26-23 |example status on 05/29/23 with even more text| 05-29-23 |example status on 07/10/23 with yet again more text| 07-10-23
3 |example status on 04/26/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 04-26-23 |example status on 05/29/23 with even more text| 05-29-23 |example status on 07/10/23 with yet again more text| 07-10-23
;
run;

I know this is a little confusing for data this was the simplest I could make the data based upon the original dataset. I would like the final product to look like the below:
data test_01;
length status_01 $175;
infile datalines dsd dlm="|" truncover;
input ID Status_01$ date_01 :mmddyy10.;
format date_01 mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1 |example status on 01/29/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 01-29-23
1 |example status on 02/06/24 with even more text| 02-06-24
1 |example status on 03/11/24 with yet again more text| 03-11-24
2 |example status on 07/17/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 07-17-23
2 |example status on 12/16/23 with even more text| 12-16-23
2 |example status on 12/24/23 with yet again more text| 12-24-23
3 |example status on 04/26/23 with more text to emphasize this is a text string| 04-26-23
3 |example status on 05/29/23 with even more text| 05-29-23
3 |example status on 07/10/23 with yet again more text| 07-10-23
;
run;

Thank you so much in advance!!!

In general for that simply an issue just use a couple of arrays and a DO loop.  Assign the values from the array to NEW variables.  For the DATE variable make sure to attach a format (preferable one that will print the dates in way that will not confuse half of your audience.)
data want;
  set test;
  array c status_01-status_03;
  array d date_01-date_03;
  do index=1 to dim(c);
    status=c[index];
    date=d[index];
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  drop status_01-status_03 date_01-date_03;
run;

But it appears that you have the same data replicated three times in your input dataset.  Is there a reason for that? With your example data you could just add these two statements after the SET statement so that only the first copy is used for each value of ID.
by id;
if first.id;

Results:

If there is no other way to remove the duplicates you might try using PROC SORT with the NODUPKEY option.

You can do this in one step. We'll use a counter to determine which row we're on within the ID group and reset it with every new ID. From there, we'll use the vvaluex function to pull the right date. vvaluex grabs the value of a variable based on its name, which we can construct with a combination of string concatenation and the scan function. For example:
foo = vvaluex('bar') returns the value of the variable bar as a string. This is useful for us because we want to dynamically select one column based on the name of another column.
We can identify the column name of the right date based on the number in the status variable. Since vvaluex returns a string, we'll convert that to a date with input. We'll then do the same exercise with the status text.
data want;
    length id 8.;
    set test;
    by id;
    array status[*] status_:;

    if(first.id) then n = 1;
        else n+1;
    
    date_01   = input(vvaluex(cats('date_', scan(vname(status[n]), 2, '_'))), mmddyy10.);
    status_01 = vvaluex(cats('status_', scan(vname(status[n]), 2, '_')));
    
    keep id status_01 date_01;
run;

id  status_01                               date_01
1   example status on 01/29/23 with ...     01/29/2023
1   example status on 02/06/24 with ...     02/06/2024
1   example status on 03/11/24 with ...     03/11/2024
2   example status on 07/17/23 with ...     07/17/2023
2   example status on 12/16/23 with ...     12/16/2023
2   example status on 12/24/23 with ...     12/24/2023
3   example status on 04/26/23 with ...     04/26/2023
3   example status on 05/29/23 with ...     05/29/2023
3   example status on 07/10/23 with ...     07/10/2023


Here is another possible solution, using a macro program to match date and status into 3 separate temporary datasets (n1,n2,n3) and then unite them
%macro prnta;
%do i = 1 %to 3;
data n&i;
set test;
rename  status_0&i = status
        date_0&i = date;
keep status_0&i date_0&i id;
run;
%end;
%mend;

%prnta;

data final;
set n1 n2 n3;
run;

proc sort data = final nodupkey;
by id date;
run;

